# Ruby on rails installation Issue on ubuntu 12.04 using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I was trying to install ruby on rails into my ubuntu 12.04 system. I have installed the rvm and then when I tried to install/update ruby this is what happened

```
joms@Joms-PC:/var/lib$ rvm -v
rvm 1.6.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
joms@Joms-PC:/var/lib$ rvm install ruby
ERROR: rvm X,Y,Z 'error' must be followed by arguments. ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

Please Help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You Probably should determine the version of Ruby you wish to install.

use: `rvm list known` to view the available options, and based on that run something like:

```
rvm install 2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scripts like [this](https://github.com/railsgirls/installation-scripts/blob/master/rails-install-ubuntu.sh) or [this](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready/blob/master/railsready.sh) to install ruby and RoR after installing system